# Good ways to work with forms in node and express

Tags: forms, node.js, express

Being new to node js and express has me wondering the best ways to get things done. Are there any specific conventions used in working with forms?

Comment: This is a pretty vague question. You should really ask more specific technical questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use express-validator to validate input fields.

Here's an example:

```
app.post('/login', routes.login.post);


//routes/login.js

exports.login.post = function(req, res){
  req.assert('username', 'Enter username').notEmpty();
  req.assert('password', 'Enter password').notEmpty();
  res.locals.err = req.validationErrors(true);

  if ( res.locals.err ) {
    if ( req.xhr ) {
      res.send(401, { err: res.locals.err });
    } else {
      res.render('login');
    }

    return;
  }

  //authenticate and set user in session here
};
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Hopefully it will help

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to pass all of your forms' data via any kind of XSS attacks or other injections filter. For example, you may use [node-validator](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator)

It's rather simple to use. To filter XSS injections, just write:

```
req.sanitize('textarea').xss();
```

etc. More docs can be found here: [node-validator](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator)

Comment: Thanks. Almost forgot about this. Would it also be necessary to escape script tags

Comment: express-validator relies on node-validator.